# Removing characters between hyphens powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to remove text that is variable. In this case the AM and file number can increase and decrease in size, so I need to find a way to remove all the characters between the hyphens (`-`). The script below is only for set characters. can anyone assist with this?

```
Get-ChildItem *.* | foreach {
    Rename-Item $_ $_.Name.Replace("AM*-", "")
}
```

File name example: `AM-#1234567-v1-filename.MSG`

Comment: There are several hyphens in the filename. Please show the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If your file names like `AM-#1234567-v1-filename.MSG` and
you want to remove the characters between the hyphens (#1234567 and v1?), you can try to do:

```
Get-ChildItem $source  *.* | foreach {
  if ($_.name -like "*-*")
   {
   $names = $_.Name.Replace($_.name.Split("-")[1], "").Replace($_.name.Split("-")[2], "").Replace("-","")
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName $names
   }  
}
```

Comment: I am struggeling to get this to work. when you say $source, are you referring to the location of the files for which I need to input this manually? Or will it take all files in the folder where the script is present.

Comment: Hello! I meen $source is a folder vs files ($source = c:\temp\yourfolder\) or something else

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to rename AM-#1234567-v1-filename.MSG as AM-filename.MSG?
If so this will work:

```
$String = "AM-#1234567-v1-filename.MSG"
$Split = $String.Split("-")
$NewName = $Split[0] + "-"  + $Split[$Split.count -1]
$NewName
```

In your loop:

```
Get-ChildItem *.* | foreach {
$Split = $_.Split("-")
$NewName = $Split[0] + "-"  + $Split[$Split.count -1]
Rename-Item $_ $NewName
```

}

Comment: You can simplify `$Split[$Split.count -1]` to `$Split[-1]`.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the assist. In regards to how I want to display the name. Basically, it comes down to the removal of all characters till the actuall file name.

Comment: a continuation of the previous comment.

previous-: AM-#1234567-v1-filename.MSG
New-: filename.MSG

Basically, a removal of all the characters before the actual file name. This is a variable and not fixed. Apologies if this was not clear before.

I have tried to run the example scripts, but I keep getting a large list of errors. See example below. I cannot add all because of the char limit. Thanks

Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "", for "Replace" to type "System.Char
": "Cannot convert value "" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exact
ly one character long.""